# How to reference oracle provider in connection string

Tags: oracle, windows-7, connection-string, provider

I had to move an application from old server to new 64bit server.

There the application used this connection string:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=XXX;User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;OLEDB.NET=True;
```

Since the oracle driver needed to be changed, I had to install a new one:
**oracle in instantclient_11_2**

Now i have problem referencing this driver in the connection string to get the application running.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle.